# ASP Classic function appears to not work after migration from Windows Server 2003 to Server 2008

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

We are in the process of migrating a few web applications from Microsoft Server 2003 to 2008 and this one function appears to not be working as the field it normally populates is empty.
Here is the code:

```
function get_name(emp_nbr)  
sql3 = "select LTRIM(RTRIM(INITCAP(COMMON_NAME))) COMMON_NAME, LTRIM(RTRIM(INITCAP(LAST_NAME))) last_name from (select EMPLOYEE_NBR,COMMON_NAME, LAST_NAME  from hrit_admin.employee union all  select   CONTRACT_RESOURCE_ID, COMMON_NAME, LAST_NAME  from   hrit_admin.contract_resource) a where EMPLOYEE_NBR = a.EMPLOYEE_NBR and EMPLOYEE_NBRr = " & emp_nbr   
rs3.open sql3,conn
get_name = rs3("COMMON_NAME") & " " & rs3("LAST_NAME") 
rs3.close
end function
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the query on the new server as straight SQL and got the correct results back?

Have you performed a simple query using that connection string?

Can you do a hello world asp classic example on the server?

Comment: All other functions of the application are working except one field.  Give me a few and I will upload a side by side comparison of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if Classic Asp is enabled. It is not by default in 2008.

Comment: In IIS?  I do have classic ASP enabled in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function get_name(emp_nbr) 
Dim CommonName,LastName,FullName 
    sql3 = "select LTRIM(RTRIM(INITCAP(COMMON_NAME))) COMMON_NAME, LTRIM(RTRIM(INITCAP(LAST_NAME))) last_name from (select EMPLOYEE_NBR,COMMON_NAME, LAST_NAME  from hrit_admin.employee union all  select   CONTRACT_RESOURCE_ID, COMMON_NAME, LAST_NAME  from   hrit_admin.contract_resource) a where EMPLOYEE_NBR = a.EMPLOYEE_NBR and EMPLOYEE_NBRr = " & emp_nbr   
    rs3.open sql3,conn
    CommonName = rs3("COMMON_NAME")
    LastName = rs3("last_name")
    rs3.close
    FullName = CommonName & " " & LastName
    get_name = FullName
end function
```

Comment: Not giving me anything, I uploaded the full page code if that helps at all, thanks for looking.  http://codeviewer.org/view/code:34b8

Comment: Does it show if you remove the initcap and trim functions ? ` sql3 = "select COMMON_NAME, LAST_NAME from (select EMPLOYEE_NBR,COMMON_NAME, LAST_NAME  from hrit_admin.employee union all  select   CONTRACT_RESOURCE_ID, COMMON_NAME, LAST_NAME  from   hrit_admin.contract_resource) a where EMPLOYEE_NBR = a.EMPLOYEE_NBR and EMPLOYEE_NBR = " & emp_nbr`

Comment: That must have gotten in there when I was editing the code to upload, it's not in the code actually on the server.  Running the query I get "missing double quote in identifier".

Comment: that must be because of the ` character in there, used to format the display here.. I was trying to see if removing the LTRIM,RTRIM and INITCAP will make any difference.

Comment: If I run this in SQL developer and provide an employee_nbr I get data back:   
    select COMMON_NAME, LAST_NAME from (select EMPLOYEE_NBR,COMMON_NAME, LAST_NAME from hrit_admin.employee union all select CONTRACT_RESOURCE_ID, COMMON_NAME, LAST_NAME from hrit_admin.contract_resource) a where EMPLOYEE_NBR = a.EMPLOYEE_NBR and EMPLOYEE_NBR = & emp_nbr

Comment: and if you try it with INITCAP ?